# jQuery Follow the cursor horizontaly with a DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

**Whiting the container I need the div to follow the cursor horizontally.
Each div had different content and this changes based on the position.**

something like this **[codepen](http://codepen.io/davide77/pen/XJRvGR)**

but the *above link* has both vertical or horizontal which is not what I need.

I've made a DEMO

```js
 $("#da-thumbs > li").hover(function () {


     $("div").show();
 }, function () {
     $("div").hide();
 });

 $('#da-thumbs > li').mousemove(function (e) {
     $("div").css({
         left: e.pageX - 120
     });
 });
```

```css
.da-thumbs {
    list-style: none;
    padding:20px;
    display:inline-block;
}
.da-thumbs li {
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    background: #000;
    float: left;
    margin: 5px;
    position: relative;
     z-index: 0;
}
.da-thumbs li a {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.da-thumbs li a div {
    display:none;
    position: relative;
    background: #777;
    background: rgba(75, 75, 75, 0.7);
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    z-index: 3;
}
.da-thumbs li a div span {
    display: block;
    padding: 10px 0;
    margin: 40px 20px 20px 20px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: normal;
    color: #fff;
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), 0 -10px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="da-thumbs" class="da-thumbs">
    <li> <a href="">
      <div><span>Menu by Simon Jensen</span></div>
    </a>

    </li>
    <li> <a href="">
      <div><span>Mr. Crabs by John Generalov</span></div>
    </a>

    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Well you should be targeting the div in the element, not all divs.

Comment: on `codepen` example there are no vertical scroll, just `hover` is disappeared. In stack snippet it works as you want i think

Comment: @demo thanks but I need it horizontal. would u be able to help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("#da-thumbs li").hover(function () {
     $(this).find("div").show();
 }, function () {
     $(this).find("div").hide();
 });

 $('#da-thumbs li').mousemove(function (e) {
     var $this = $(this);
     $this.find("div").css({
         left: e.pageX - $this.position().left - 120
     });
 });
```

Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/o1sxkuaw/) with working code.

But with this you will totally lack the "easing"/animation that the demo you linked has. If that's something you want you would have to use a different approach. If so, maybe that's something I can help you with too.

Comment: thank you so much! that's brilliant! and yes, would be perfect if you could indicate or help me with that approach. would yuo?

Comment: my idea was trying to have something smooth, where the box keep the shape and doesn't get hidden, like: http://jsfiddle.net/o1sxkuaw/1/
and  only the content(text) changes.

Comment: could you help me with this please? could u double check my fiddle?

Comment: Do you want the same effect as the [codepen](http://codepen.io/davide77/pen/XJRvGR)-link but without hover events from top/below?

Answer (score 0):

Why use JavaScript at all?

```js
$("#da-thumbs").on("mousemove", "li", function (evt) {
    var li = $(this),
        offX = li.offset().left,
        width = li.width(),
        x = evt.clientX;      
        li.toggleClass("right", x-offX>width/2);
});
```

```css
.da-thumbs li:hover a div,  /* slides div in on hover */
.da-thumbs li.right:hover a div{  
    transition: 1s;   /* sets amount of time for the animation */
    margin-left: 0;   /* positioned with margin instead of left */
    margin-right: 0;
}

.da-thumbs li.right a div {
    margin-left: 600px;
}

.da-thumbs {
    list-style: none;
    padding:20px;
    display:inline-block;
}
.da-thumbs li {
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    background: #000;
    float: left;
    margin: 5px;
    position: relative;
     z-index: 0;
  overflow: hidden;   /*Hide the overflow */
}
x.da-thumbs li a {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.da-thumbs li a div {
    transition: 1s;    /*slides div out */
    position: relative;
    background: #777;
    background: rgba(75, 75, 75, 0.7);
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    z-index: 3;
    margin-left:-300px; /* positioned with margin instead of left */
}
.da-thumbs li a div span {
    display: block;
    padding: 10px 0;
    margin: 40px 20px 20px 20px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: normal;
    color: #fff;
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), 0 -10px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="da-thumbs" class="da-thumbs">
    <li> <a href="">
      <div><span>Menu by Simon Jensen</span></div>
    </a>

    </li>
    <li> <a href="">
      <div><span>Mr. Crabs by John Generalov</span></div>
    </a>

    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: thanks but is not what I need. I need the hidden div to follow the mouse. would u be able to help? like the codepen demo

Comment: I just need to get JS to know which element the mouse is over